# While implementing VARMAX model in python, the error comes that leading minor is not positive definite

Tags: python, statsmodels, arima, varmax

I am working on time series VARMAX model in python with 18000 rows of data and 6 parameters. Repeatedly while fitting the VARMAX model, it says " leading minor is not positive definite" or "matrix is not positive definite". Can somebody help in recognizing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The error suggests that there are linear dependencies among your variables. You can investigate these linear relationships using the correlation matrix `df.corr()` and/or PCA.